# Kadane's algorithms to leetcode "121 Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock"

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, comparative-review, memory-optimization

I employed the conventional Kadane's algorithms to solve a maximum subarray problem in leetcode  [Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock/)

## Description

> 121. Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock
>
> Say you have an array for which the *i*th element is the price of a given stock on day *i*.
>
> If you were only permitted to complete at most one transaction (i.e., buy one and sell one share of the stock), design an algorithm to find the maximum profit.
>
> Note that you cannot sell a stock before you buy one.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: [7,1,5,3,6,4]
> Output: 5
> Explanation: Buy on day 2 (price = 1) and sell on day 5 (price = 6), profit = 6-1 = 5.
>              Not 7-1 = 6, as selling price needs to be larger than buying price.
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: [7,6,4,3,1]
> Output: 0
> Explanation: In this case, no transaction is done, i.e. max profit = 0.
> ```

## My solution

```py
class Solution:
    def maxProfit(self, prices):
        """
        :type prices: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if not prices:
            return 0
        local_max = global_max = 0
        gains = [prices[i]-prices[i-1] for i in range(1, len(prices))]
        for cur in gains:
            local_max = max(local_max + cur, cur)
            global_max = max(global_max, local_max)
        return global_max
```

> Runtime: 64 ms, faster than 14.96% of Python3 online submissions for Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock.
>
> Memory Usage: 14 MB, less than 5.08% of Python3 online submissions for Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock

```py
class Solution:
    def maxProfit(self, prices):
        """
        :type prices: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if not prices:
            return 0
        loc = glo = 0
        for i in range(1, len(prices)):
            loc = max(loc+prices[i]-prices[i-1], prices[i]-prices[i-1])
            glo = max(glo, loc)
        return glo
```

> Runtime: 48 ms, faster than 53.38% of Python3 online submissions for Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock.
>
> Memory Usage: 13.8 MB, less than 5.08% of Python3 online submissions for Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock

## TestCase

```
class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.solution = Solution3()

    def test_a(self):
        prices = [7,1,5,3,6,4]
        answer = 5
        check = self.solution.maxProfit(prices)
        self.assertEqual(answer, check)

    def test_b(self):
        prices = [1,2,3,4,5]
        answer = 4
        check = self.solution.maxProfit(prices)
        self.assertEqual(answer, check)

    def test_c(self):
        prices = [7,6,4,3,1]
        answer = 0
        check = self.solution.maxProfit(prices)
        self.assertEqual(answer, check)        

unittest.main()
```

The memory usage ranks very low.